# Microsoft Azure iiS Manager Url re-write

Tags: url, azure, iis, iis-manager

I've been playing around with Microsoft's iiS manager, and I can't manage to get the URL's to re-write. I'm trying to re-write: "products.html" as "products", and I just can't get my head around it.

For the pattern I've been using: ^products

For the re-write URL I've been using: products?id={R:0}

Everything else I left on the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is because all your "pages" match the pattern `^products` - [Read User Friendly URL - rule template](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template). The article.aspx example describes a solution to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've checked through the documentation and they have not provided a rewrite pattern for .html

Comment: It is no different than rewriting .xxx, .aspx, .png or nay other extension.